# RootVisual is null when returning from Tombstoning?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, rad-controls, tombstoning

Hi I just found out that my application was crashing when returning from tombstoning. I was able to target the problem here inside the constructor of my page:

```
RadPhoneApplicationFrame frame = App.Current.RootVisual as RadPhoneApplicationFrame;
frame.PageTransitionCompleted += 
                         new EventHandler<EventArgs>(frame_PageTransitionCompleted);
```

Everytime the app is Re-Activated the RootVisual is setting the frame to null. I'm wondering if there is a casting issue here because before I used this code my tombstoning was working perfectly and I was able to navigate freely throughout the app. Any ideas on what might be causing this? Or maybe a work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should move this code from page constructor to `OnNavigatedTo` method override in your page. Reason is that `RootVisual` is probably set in `RootFrame.Navigated` event handler which is generated after page is constructed, not before (this depends of implementation in your `App.xaml.cs`).

Of course because `OnNavigatedTo` method may be runned more that once for a page, you should make sure that `PageTransitionCompleted` event handler is not assigned two times (just use `-=` before `+=`).

Another option is to move this code to `App.xaml.cs`. This makes sense most to me, because that `PageTransitionCompleted` event is related to whole app, not a single page.